# How to make this Auth Hwid

Tags: c#, php, hwid

I have this code from some Source and I want to make Auth for it but i dont know how to make HWID Check. Because i need web files!

Here is the C# Visual Studio Code of Auth Program:
I need something like this https://xtool3.000webhostapp.com/auth.php?action=check&hwid=

Here is the Code:    https://ghostbin.com/paste/33otj

Can someone help me to make this php so i can upload it to my web server.

Comment: Hi, consider pasting the code directly into your question following the SO best ways to ask. People here are willing to help you solving any problem you have. However, clicking into multiple links to get context is not a good way.